# How to get specific urls from a website in a class tag with beautiful soup? (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

---

I'm trying to get the urls of the main articles from a news outlet using beautiful soup. Since I do not want to get ALL of the links on the entire page, I specified the class. My code only manages to display the titles of the news articles, not the links. This is the website: https://www.reuters.com/news/us

Here is what I have so far:

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/news/us').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "story-title"})

for i in links:
    print(i.get_text().strip())
    print()
```

---

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get link to all articles you can use following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/news/us').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "story-content"})

for i in links:
    print(i.a.get('href'))
```

Comment: I did have to concatenate with "reuters.com" at the beginning of the print statement, but this works, thank you!